# Algorithm and Hint for Scientific Calculator

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I have a Scientific Calculator project using Java Swing. but, I ended up in wrong calculation. Example: If push button:

1 then + then 2 then  * then 3 the answer is 9, not 7.

Could you give me a hint, I must use what classes? And how about the algorithm to make it right answer?

Thank you

```
class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                CalculatorFrame frame = new CalculatorFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}


class CalculatorFrame extends JFrame{
    public CalculatorFrame(){
    setTitle("Calculator");
    CalculatorPanel panel = new CalculatorPanel();
    add(panel);
    pack();
    }
}


class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel{
    public CalculatorPanel(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        result = 0;
        lastCommand = "=";
        start = true;
        // add the display
        display = new JButton("");
        display.setEnabled(false);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        ActionListener insert = new InsertAction();
        ActionListener command = new CommandAction();
        // add the buttons in a  x  grid
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4 ));
        addButton("7", insert);
        addButton("8", insert);
        addButton("9", insert);
        addButton("/", command);

        addButton("4", insert);
        addButton("5", insert);
        addButton("6", insert);
        addButton("*", command);

        addButton("1", insert);
        addButton("2", insert);
        addButton("3", insert);
        addButton("-", command);
        addButton("0", insert);
        addButton(".", insert);
        addButton("=", command);
        addButton("+", command);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void addButton(String label, ActionListener listener){
        JButton button = new JButton(label);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        panel.add(button);
    }

    private class InsertAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String input = event.getActionCommand();
            if (start){
                display.setText("");
                start = false;
            }
            display.setText(display.getText() + input);
        }
    }


    private class CommandAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String command = event.getActionCommand();

            if (start){
                if (command.equals("-")){
                display.setText(command);
                start = false;
                }
                else lastCommand = command;
            }
            else{
                calculate(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
                lastCommand = command;
                start = true;
            }
        }
    }


    public void calculate(double x){
        if (lastCommand.equals("+")) result += x;
        else if (lastCommand.equals("-")) result -= x;
        else if (lastCommand.equals("*")) result *= x;
        else if (lastCommand.equals("/")) result /= x;
        else if (lastCommand.equals("=")) result = x;
        display.setText("" + result);
    }

    private JButton display;
    private JPanel panel;
    private double result;
    private String lastCommand;
    private boolean start;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to give us something more to work with. This makes no sense at all.

Comment: my code for calculation make it wrong answer. In math, 1+2*3 the answer is 7.

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag your question as such. (I'm assuming it is since you said it's a project.)

Comment: Read up on "operator precedence parsing."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also create String with some mathematical task and use it in JavaScript engine to calculate it. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html).

```
// create a script engine manager
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
// create a JavaScript engine
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

Double d=(Double)engine.eval("1 + 2 * 3");
System.out.println(d);
```

output `7.0`

Comment: thank you. I try to use ScriptEngineManager and ScriptEngine and my calculation works well.

Answer (score 1):

My approach for this would be to represent operations as objects. (Classes like `Number`, `Add`, `Multiply`, that hold the operands as fields and have a `getValue()` method.) As the user presses buttons (except `=`), you build up a tree of such objects according to the precedence rules of maths, so you can calculate the result of the whole expression when the user presses `=`.

Alternatively, store the expression as a string, then parse it in one go in the end.