# Giving brackets precedence

Tags: java, calculator, brackets, operator-precedence

I'm very new to java and I'm building a calculator, that takes an equation and evaluates it.

I'm using the Scanner method to get an input, but this means my input is a Scanner type. What should I do to this input so I can evaluate it? And once I can evaluate it, how can i give precedence to brackets?

For example, for the equation (5*(4+3))*2 , I'd like the program to evaluate (4+3) first, then have it multiplied by 4, then all of that multiplied by 2.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll have to read in your expression (not equation, since there's no equal sign involved) as a String and parse it. Using a `Scanner` doesn't get you very far in this process, other than reading a line of text.

Comment: What you did is correct, precedence is given from left to right. Or you can use ((4+3)*5)*2. The inner brackets are evaluated first.

Comment: Put your operators,including brackets, into a stack.

Comment: Can you use already implemented evaluation mechanisms [like JavaScript engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11261225/1393766) or you want/must create your own mechanism?

Comment: @AdnanZahid Precedence is not 'given from left to right', whatever that means, and what he did is not correct. He should evaluate 4+3, multiply by 5, then multiply by 2.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is Dijkstra's [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). This converts in-fix mathematical notation into post-fix notation, which neatly sorts out all problems with operator precedence and brackets as post-fix notation has no need for either of them. The Wikipedia page has a full example in C, which could be translated into Java.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful: [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) and [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). They explain the idea of how to divide the string in a tree and execute one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

@Simon G's suggestion of suggestion of using Dijkstra's Shunting Yard algorithm has nailed it.  You will need to implement the "micro-grammar" for parsing the symbols, but `Scanner` can do 95% of the work.

An alternative would be to implement the expression parser using a parser generator such as ANTLR or Javacc, and then implement evaluation as a traversal of the tree.  But that's rather heavyweight if you simply want to evaluate the expression once.

Finally, I want to note that while this is a well known (solved) problem, it is not a trivial one ... in any language.  And maybe this is telling you that you need to do some more reading on algorithms and/or compilers to round out your knowledge.

Comment: Recursive descent is another possibility, and probably my first choice, but then I already know how to do it ;-)